# Сhanging the default “Add To Cart” button text in WooCommerce for each language

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to change the default “Add To Cart” button text to ”Buy now“. I solved it by adding such a function to the function.php file of the child theme:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'replace_cart_text');
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'replace_cart_text');
function replace_cart_text()
{
    return 'Buy now';
}
```

The problem is that I use different languages on the site. How to modify function to display different text on the buttons for each language? My translation plugin is Polylang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by adding condition to the function:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'replace_cart_text');
add_filter('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'replace_cart_text');
function replace_cart_text() {
    if (get_locale() == 'de_DE') {
        return 'Kaufen';
    }
    if (get_locale() == 'en_US') {
        return 'Buy now';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the plugin references in the below link for a better translation for woocommerce.

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/woocommerce-multilingual/

Comment: Thank you. I know how to translate .po and .mo files. But that's not the point. The problem is that I want to replace the default text on the button for each language.